# Как сделать редирект с категории сайта?

Tags: .htaccess

Всем привет!

Помогите, пожалуйста, как сделать редиректы?

С `site.com/blog/post-324` на `blog.site.com/post-324`?

То есть как добиться результата чтобы был редирект с `site.com/blog/` на `blog.site.com/` а ссылки на посты сохранялись.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте как вариант

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^blog\/(.*)$ http: //blog.site.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]